# How is a media library like WinAmp's implemented?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, media-player, media-library

I wonder because the access times are quite short, even for complex expressions (`(playcount = "0" OR lastplay < [1 year ago]) AND rating != "1" AND rating != "2" AND filename NOTHAS "Midis & Modules" AND type = "0"`) so basically it behaves like a map from everything to filename, right? What kind of data structure is utilized to get such a fast access?

Answer (score 0):

Relational database like SQLite, with well-defined indexes on popular fields will handle it easily.